# "How To Ask" block in MSO doesn't encourage discussion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The "[Ask a Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" page in ***meta*.stackoverflow.com** has this block of text to the right of the question:

> ### How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about the Stack Overflow engine or websites?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be
>   *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> etc..

However, MSO is specifically meant to be a discussion area.  A place where SO and its sister sites can be discussed without fear of being closed or downvoted as being subjective, belonging on UV or belonging in the SOFAQ.

The text of the "How To Ask" block should reflect that.

Comment: "...without fear of being closed or downvoted as being subjective" - Sad. Where is the thrill? :)

Comment: You're right... I should have written, "without fear of offending somebody with a subjective question"

Comment: The How To Ask page still says the same as before.  In what sense is this completed?

Comment: It has changed from what I can see. It now refers to the Stackoverflow family of sites.

Comment: ok.  I guess it took a while to propagate.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I think that this is one of the core values on stackoverflow - it does discourage discussions that are not productive.

If there is no result/solution/answer the entire discussion would be useless and just a waste of time for both the participants and the readers.

Comment: He's talking about MetaSO, not SO.